# Checking if 2 intervals overlap in Scheme

Tags: scheme, intervals, overlap

So basically I've been given a question to this language which I've been reading the documentation on since early last night. I don't know a thing yet so I figured I'd give this website a try.

Basically what question here is this:

I've been given several structures for calendar dates and an interval in scheme:

```
    (define-struct cal (month day))

    (define-struct interval (start end))
```

However I'm being asked to check if 2 different intervals overlap each other. An example to this:

```
    If I have dates March 12th - March 14th in my first interval, 
    but in my second interval I have the dates March 13th - March 2th
    (overlap? int1 int2) would return true.

    However if I have dates March 12th - March 14th in my first interval,
    but I have March 15th - March 18th in my second interval
    (overlap? int1 int2) would return false.
```

I don't know where to start with this. If anyone can clear this up for me so I can finish this problem I would be grateful. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

A good approach in general when writing programs is to break a problem down into more manageable ones. So, before tackling the problem of comparing two intervals, try tackling the simpler problem of comparing two calendar dates. Given two dates `a` and `b`, try to write a function that returns true if `a` is before `b`, and false otherwise. So,

```
; date1 is January 5, date2 is February 6
(before? date1 date2) ; returns true
; date1 is January 5, date2 is January 2
(before? date1 date2) ; return false
```

Next, think about how you might use `before?` to construct `overlap?`. In particular, consider this: if two intervals *do not* overlap, then the end date of one comes *before* the start date of the other.

Finally, consider the edge cases - what do you want your program to do if given, for example, (January 4 to March 6) and (March 6 to December 3) ? Do these intervals overlap or not?

Happy coding!

PS - if you need more help, don't be afraid to ask. I'm being deliberately vague because I thought that giving you hints would be better than just plopping a solution down in front of you - that way you wouldn't learn anything.

Comment: To answer your Jan 4 - March 6 and March 6 - December 3, yes if there is any date that is the same in both intervals, they are both considered as overlapping so it would return true.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Ord's excellent advice, if you're looking for more basic information: what does define-struct mean? How do I write a function that uses dates?--then I would suggest you take a look at the (free, online) textbook [How To Design Programs, version 2e](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/). It looks like you're interested in Section 2.5, "Adding Structure", but it may be hard to understand this section without reading earlier ones, as well.

Good luck!